# Python .replace() function not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out why the .replace function in python isn't functioning correctly. I have spent the entire day yesterday searching for an answer but alas have not found one.

I'm trying to open and read a file, copy it into a list, count the number of lines in the list and remove all the punctuation (ie , . ! ? etc). I can do everything except remove the punctuation (and I must use the .replace function instead of importing a module).

```
with open('Small_text_file.txt', 'r') as myFile:        #adding lines from file to list
contents = myFile.readlines()
fileList= []
# punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
for i in contents:
    fileList.append(i.rstrip())

print('The Statistics are:\n','Number of lines:', len(fileList)) #first part of question



for item in fileList:
    fileList = item.replace(',', "")
    fileList = item.replace('.', "")

print(fileList)
```

The "Small text file" is:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus condimentum sagittis lacus? laoreet luctus ligula laoreet ut.
Vestibulum ullamcorper accumsan velit vel vehicula?
Proin tempor lacus arcu. Nunc at elit condimentum, semper nisi et, condimentum mi.
In venenatis blandit nibh at sollicitudin. Vestibulum dapibus mauris at orci maximus pellentesque.
Nullam id elementum ipsum. Suspendisse*

**Running the code returns the following:**

The Statistics are:

Number of lines: 6

Nullam id elementum ipsum Suspendisse

So the code DOES remove the comma and period characters but it also removes the preceding 5 lines of the text and only prints the very last line. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why the downvotes? except for the title, a much better question than many around. the OP blames .replace, while the problem is assignment, is that what you downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
for i,item in enumerate(fileList):
    fileList[i] = item.replace(',', "").replace('.', "")
```

Without enumerate,

```
for i in range(len(fileList)):
    fileList[i] = fileList[i].replace(',', "").replace('.', "")
```

Comment: The code you posted returns the following:

"The Statistics are:

 Number of lines: 6

['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Vivamus condimentum sagittis lacus? laoreet luctus ligula laoreet ut.', 'Vestibulum ullamcorper accumsan velit vel vehicula?', 'Proin tempor lacus arcu. Nunc at elit condimentum, semper nisi et, condimentum mi.', 'In venenatis blandit nibh at sollicitudin. Vestibulum dapibus mauris at orci maximus pellentesque.', 'Nullam id elementum ipsum. Suspendisse']

So it does not delete the whole text file but also doesn't remove the punctuation

Comment: Let me check, must have missed something

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ok, thank you that works but I have not come across the "enumerate" function before. From a quick glance I see that it enumerate adds a count. Can that code somehow be written without the enumerate function. Ie. count = 0.....count +=1 But nonetheless thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated the answer, added the code without `enumerate`.

Comment: @StannisBarratheon The original problem was that you were changing `item`, but that is a copy of the item in the list, you were not changing the list itself - that's why you need the index number `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for x, item in enumerate(fileList): 
    fileList[x] = item.replace(',', "").replace('.', "")
```

*Note*: `item.replace()` returns replaced string which you need to store in the right index of list. `enumerate` helps you keep track of index while iterating through the list.

Comment: Ok, thank you that works but I have not come across the "enumerate" function before. From a quick glance I see that it enumerate adds a count. Can that code somehow be written without the enumerate function. Ie. count = 0.....count +=1 But nonetheless thanks for your help.

Edit: Previous responder updated their code. Cheers

Comment: you can do the same thing in a loop over len(fileList), but `enumerate` is preferred, it keeps code compact and readable.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I'm aware. I gave more importance to a precise, readable code. Thanks.

Comment: @Austin, my comment was towards OP comment asking to do without enumerate. You can, but you shouldn't. )